# Devise validate user email to end in @berkeley.edu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation, devise

Trying to validate users that sign up on my site to have an email address that ends in @berkeley.edu, but it seems like the regex validation I made is making some errors.

This is what I have in my User.rb file:

```
validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :format => {:with => /\A[\w+\-.]+@(berkeley|uw)\.edu\z/i}
```

Any ideas?

**Forgot to mention** Error message I'm getting is "email is already taken" when it clearly isn't already in the Users table. And it creates the user anyway, so I don't know what the issue is.

Comment: whats the error you are getting

Comment: try `^` and `$` with `,:multiline => true`

Comment: Just updated my post. The error is "Email is already taken" when I know for sure it isn't already in the User table, and it even creates the user.

Comment: same questions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678874/devise-email-already-taken-error-but-account-is-created ?

Comment: @aelor - not sure what you mean, could you show me?

Comment: `validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :format => {:with => /^[\w+\-.]+@(berkeley|uw)\.edu$/i}, :multiline => true`

Comment: hope you are using rails 4

Comment: I'll give this a try, but it sounds like this might be insecure to JavaScript vulnerabilities?

Comment: Nevermind, multiline fixes that.

Comment: Do you see `validatable` included in `User` model?

Answer (score 0):

Define a custom validator

```
validate :check_email

def check_email
  errors.add(:email, "your error message") unless self.email.include? "@berkeley.edu"  
end
```